# Test for QueryException

Tags: apex, exception, queryexception

I have some code wich I need test and there I have some problem

```
try {

            Contact checkContact = [SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, Email FROM Contact WHERE Email = :email];

    } catch (QueryException e){

            if (e.getMessage().equals('List has no rows for assignment to SObject')){

                // some code (tested)

            } else {

                // how can I test this situation

            }
    }
```

Comment: One way would be to use a dynamic SOQL query and make it malformed, something like 'SELECT Id WHERE Id = ...whatever you want here'. You *should* get an error message pertaining to a `FROM` statement missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to throw any other error, not sure if this is the right thing you want to test. Consider rewriting your logic, probably you are looking for something like this:

```
try {
    Contact checkContact = [SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, Email FROM Contact WHERE Email = :email];
    // untested yet
}
catch (QueryException e){
    // some code (tested)
}
```

But to answer your question, you could create another test with two contacs having the same email (as defined in your soql `:email`). It would fail for having more than one results.

Comment: how about the other approach? what kind of Error are you trying to catch there? I can't imagine anything else.

Comment: empty email is work for "List has more than 1 row for assignment to SObject"